# Calling jQuery function using C# CodeBehind with return value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application that will be used to display information from a server regarding various sites for a water company. I have a jQuery method that returns the text of the hyperlink which has been clicked within the div 'info':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#info a').click(function getName()
        {
            return ($(this).text());
        });
</script>
```

I can call this method using C# codebehind using the code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "getName()", true);
```

However I cannot get its return value, which is what I need. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You cannot call client side script and get return values in server side code.  If you want your server code to react to a link being clicked then there are options (submit the form with a hidden field or use an ajax call, for example), but what you've got above simply won't work.  I'd strongly recommend that you do some reading about the [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx);

Comment: the question is where you want to set those values , just update the value of that control ? why is return required?

Comment: I agree with @Archer, use ajax call or hidden field

Comment: or embedded code behind C# `<% SeverSideProperties %>` ?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad He's trying to `return` the value of a client-side script to a server function.

Comment: I need the name of the site (which is the text of the hyperlink which is clicked) which is then appended to a url via QueryString so the  site.aspx page is displayed showing the results for that site.

Comment: @Archer: You're correct , but the description was very confusing and seemed other way round.

Comment: @PhilipLoffler: If the hyperlink is simply going to redirect why not create the hyperlink in that way(dynamically) in JS itself ? Is there a need to hit the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenField" name="myhiddenField" runat="server" />
```

And JQuery (*have not tested this*) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#info a').click(function getName()
        {
            $("#myhiddenField").val($(this).text());
        });
</script>
```

And then you would be able to access hidden field in code behind `myhiddenField.Value`.

Or if you want to use Ajax Call see tutorial [here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

***EDIT :***

I created a little project and the below works fine for me (I get alert "testing"):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#info a').click(function getName() {
                // As control having runat="server" their ids get changed
                // selector would be like this 
                $("#<%= myhiddenField.ClientID %>").val($(this).text());
                alert($("#<%= myhiddenField.ClientID %>").val());
            });
        });
</script>

<div id="info">
  <a href="#">testing</a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenField" name="myhiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks. What C# code will I need to access this hidden field? Sorry I am fairly new to ASP

Comment: You can use it like any other field try myhiddenField.Value - updated answer

Comment: I am not able to access myHiddenField (does not exist in current context)

Comment: oops forgot runat="server" in hidden field. try that please :)

Comment: Everything runs smoothly but myHiddenField.Value comes back without a value, is it null for some reason?

Comment: might be that JQuery does not assign a value(as I said haven't tested it) so put an alert in JQuery and see if hidden field gets populated...

Comment: Using alert() in jquery the only thing that is returned is [object Object] thoughts?

Comment: do alert($("#myhiddenField").val()); see what you get?

Comment: what is the result of alert($(this).text());

Comment: "site1" the value I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire a button click event from JavaScript in ASP.NET after the document ready

like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "$(function() {
$( ‘#info a
‘ ).click(); });
", true);
```

for more details see [Click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this
Calling Javascript function on code behind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

And If you have UpdatePanel there then try like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

---

**Updated Answer:**

**Client Side :**  Create a function and set value to hidden field as clientside , and on serverside call this function and get hiddenfield value

**JS:**

```
  function myFunc(){
     //set you value to hiddenfield
     $(".hdfiled").val("Hello");
      alert($(".hdfiled").val());
    }
```

**Code behind :** Here am calling `myFunc` from serverside as your Title says *call function from CODE BEHIND*

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:myFunc(); ", true);
string getHd_Value=  myhiddenField.value;
```

**[JS FIDDLE TO check hiddenfield values](http://jsfiddle.net/8uQsu/)**

Comment: These work for calling the function however I cannot get the function's return value - is there any additional code I can use to grab the return value?

Comment: He's trying to `return` the value of a client-side script to a server function.