# call popup panel on page load in asp.net code behind using jquery control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to show the modal window (executed in the `JavaScript` function below) on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {    
    $('.popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({
        openButton: '.clicker', 
        closeButton: '#close-btn', 
        isModal: true 
    });    
});

</script>

<asp:HyperLink ID="clic" Text="ck" runat="server" CssClass="clicker" NavigateUrl="#">
</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:Panel ID="cli" runat="server" CssClass="popup-wrapper" Width="500" Height="500" >  
    <a href="#" id="A1">Close</a>    
</asp:Panel>
```

How do I do this in asp.net?

Comment: i want to show it on page load

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

$('.popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({ openButton: '.clicker', closeButton: '#close-btn', isModal: true });

});

</script>

<asp:HyperLink ID="clic" Text="ck" runat="server" CssClass="clicker" NavigateUrl="#"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:Panel ID="cli" runat="server" CssClass="popup-wrapper" Width="500" Height="500" >

<a href="#" id="A1">Close</a>

</asp:Panel>

now it is connected with link
tell me any updation so i can call it on page load event in asp.net

Comment: it is connteced with hyper link but i want to call it on page load on code behind pageload event

Comment: might this link will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111890/calling-jquery-function-using-c-sharp-codebehind-with-return-value

Comment: user3201772,it will be better if you post code from comments to question by editing your post

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to show up on every page load, you can use `JQuery` `.ready()` function on the `document` object, which will execute this script when the DOM fully loads. Otherwise, what might be happening is you're executing the function before `$('.popup-wrapper').modalPopLite()` or whatever is initialized and getting a `JavaScript` error.

So you'd do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({
        openButton: '.clicker', 
        closeButton: '#close-btn', 
        isModal: true 
    });    
});
```

Now, if you want to only display this on the first page load, and not on any further postbacks, you'll need to tap into C# codebehind:

```
public partial class SomePage : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // The @ character denotes a string literal; just makes it easy to 
            // use multiple lines in this case and keep the inline javascript 
            // code looking nicely formatted within C#

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopModal", @"
                $(document).ready(function () {    
                    $('.popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({
                        openButton: '.clicker', 
                        closeButton: '#close-btn', 
                        isModal: true 
                    });    
                });"
            );
        }
    }
}
```